# Is it normal for a registrar to charge for nameserver changes?

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registrar

My registrar, `34sp.com`, wants to charge for changing nameservers for a domain.

The domain is a `.cc` domain. If this matters.

Is this normal? I've never heard of this before. Almost $30 US for a nameserver change?! Surely this is just a text file?

Comment: Perhaps if you do it yourself it is free but if you get them to do it they charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some smaller registrars that don't provide an automated end-user control panel do charge for DNS changes. Some of these registrars only sell domains as an additional service and often entice you in with low (or even free) initial registration costs. Another thing to watch out for is that if they are charging for DNS changes then they are also likely to charge you if you transfer your domain away.

These companies are best avoided in my opinion for your domain registration as it can only cost you more or give you hassle in the long term.

There are many other (larger?) registrars that provide a fully automated service, so you can edit the DNS zone and change NAMESERVERS whenever you like and not incur any additional cost. Ideally, there should be no cost if you wish to transfer to another registrar in this case.

AFAIK there are no additional charges for specific TLDs? Apart from the registration/renewal costs. Or maybe the larger companies absorb these charges into their renewal costs??

**34sp.com** - a little puzzling since they advertise:

- Full DNS (domain name server) Control
- Advanced DNS Control Panel including MX Record Control
- Complete Name Server Management

I can't see anything in [their T&Cs](http://www.34sp.com/termsandconditions) that relate to additional costs, however, they do state:

> 5.3 Where the Customer wishes to transfer ownership of a domain to a third party 34SP.com reserve the right to charge an administration fee as appropriate for effecting the transfer.

Also, they do not appear to offer `.cc` domains for registration? Did you transfer this domain to 34sp.com?

Comment: I bought it over a decade ago from them. it's definitely time to move on I think.

Comment: +1 I've never encountered this, but strictly speaking they can charge whatever they want for their services. It's common enough *not* to that I'd just leave.

Answer (score 1):

Never happened to me, most known registrars give you this option for free. However, if they do it to everyone and that is their pricing?! Transfer your domain elsewhere.

Comment: I intend to do this. When I questioned it, they told me in an email:

"Changing the nameservers isn't a charge *we* impose, it'll be a charge enforced by the main registrars. I.e. for .cc domains, it'll cost you in either case"

Comment: @KevinSedgley: "_main_ registrars" - aren't they (34sp.com) _the_ registrars?

Comment: Yes they are. I thought it sounded like nonsense when they sent the email.

Comment: @KevinSedgley I think you're unclear on the difference between [registrar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar) and [registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registry). The .cc registry is [eNIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cc), they seem to charge for nameserver changes.

Comment: -1. This Answer is wrong - see @Perleone comment.

Comment: @AKTed: I don't think this answer is necessarily wrong - it is true that many registrars (that have automated control panels) do give you the option to change the NAMESERVERS at no additional cost - even for `.cc` domains.

Comment: @Perleone: "they seem to charge for nameserver changes" - do you have a reference where this is stated?

Comment: @KevinSedgley No, I just referred to you first comment here, "they told me in an email ...".